What roll to knot ropes?
First time ever we came into the situation where we had 2 ropes that needed to be knotted together to hold a very high amount of weight (for climbing, and helping someone who can't climb himself). Thus it was decided that a skillcheck is appropriate there.
Where we stumbled and fell is, what skill would it be?
I would have went for crafting from the skill descriptions alone, but others seem to go for thievery or survival.
What is correct here?

In addition to crafting/thievery/survival I'd probably allow an appropriate Lore skill. Sailing/military lore likely includes knot-tying, even if the background doesn't explicitly grant survival as a skill. Part of me also wonders like... does it make sense for a bunch of experienced adventurers to not be familiar with climbing knots? Maybe, depending on the setting, but in a lot of cases I'd just give it to them.

The rules don't say
It's hard to prove a negative, but searches like 'tying', 'knot' and 'rope' don't produce any relevant results other than the Legacy 2e spell animate rope and Held Item Rope of Climbing, neither of which answer the question (but provide useful information). The only other relevant rule I know of is in the Escape action.
Escape:

You attempt to escape from being grabbed, immobilized, or restrained. Choose one creature, object, spell effect, hazard, or other impediment imposing any of those conditions on you. Attempt a check using your unarmed attack modifier against the DC of the effect. This is typically the Athletics DC of a creature grabbing you, the Thievery DC of a creature who tied you up, the spell DC for a spell effect, or the listed Escape DC of an object, hazard, or other impediment. You can attempt an Acrobatics or Athletics check instead of using your attack modifier if you choose (but this action still has the attack trait).

Clearly, this makes a case for rope use being tied to Thievery.

Ultimately, however, that does not say that that is the way to tie a knot (and, in fact, trying to tie someone up is significantly more complicated than making a load-bearing knot). The true answer is that, because the rules don't say, it's completely up to the GM. First, they must determine if a roll is even necessary.

When success isn't certain—whether you're swinging a sword at a foul beast, attempting to leap across a chasm, or straining to remember the name of the earl's second cousin at a soiree—you'll attempt a check.

A sufficiently capable character may not need to roll anything if the GM thinks that they could just accomplish the task. If they feel it is important to determine if the knot will be successful, they next have to choose a skill to use. From Adjudicating Rules:

While GMing, strive to make quick, fair, and consistent rulings. Your rulings should encourage your group to work together to interpret the rules and be creative with their characters' decisions and actions.

If you're not sure what action a task uses, look for the most similar basic action. If you don't find one, make up an undefined action and add any necessary traits (usually attack, concentrate, manipulate, or move).
If you don't know what check to use, pick the most appropriate skill. If no other skill applies to a check to Recall Knowledge, use an appropriate Lore skill (usually at an untrained proficiency rank).


They don't have to pick one skill. They can group-source to see what the players/characters would suggest/try and go with something the group feels good about. They may have forgotten that one of them has Lore: Sailing that is suddenly very relevant.
Finally, they need a DC. This is where the relevant spell/item I mentioned before come in handy. Tying a knot is fairly easy once you know how to do it, and it does not get much harder depending on what you're trying to accomplish with the knot. It can be accomplished with a Rank 1 spell, or level 3 item. From the advice on setting DC's, rope tying is probably a Simple DC of Untrained (10) or Trained (15), possibly with an Easy/Hard Adjustment (+/-2).
